# Many to many relationship with SQLAlchemy fails with 'Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables'

Tags: json, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I've successfully set up an API endpoint using SQLAlchemy. The new goal is to get the json returned with a nested array of `tag` objects. So that I end up with something like this:

```
{
    "favourite": "0",
    "location": {
        "urbanisation": "Montreal",
        "province": "Quebec"
    },
    "tags":[{
            "name":"celebration"
        },
        {
            "name":"national holiday"
        },
    
    ],
    "count_articles": 5,
    "scheduled": "1",
    "title": "TEST TITLE",
    "count_video": 5,
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2020-09-08",
    "count_audio": 5,
    "summary": "TEST DESCRIPTION"
}
```

### Attempt 1:

I know that I can create a [many to many relationship in SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html) and have modified my python and database in order to do accommodate this change.

[image: The joining table events_tags]

Here's how the joining table is handled

```
#JOINING TABLE FOR EVENTS AND TAGS
tag_association_table = Table('events_tags', db.metadata,
    db.Column('event_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('events.id')),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id'))
)
```

And here's the full code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from json import dumps
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema, fields, auto_field
from flask_cors import CORS
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

import mysql.connector

#SQLAlchemy Docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost/news'
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
api = Api(app)

#JOINING TABLE FOR EVENTS AND TAGS
tag_association_table = Table('events_tags', db.metadata,
    db.Column('event_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('events.id')),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id'))
)

#MODELS FOR EVENTS RESOURCE
class EventModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "events"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    summary = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    scheduled = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    favourite = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    count_audio = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    count_video = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    count_articles = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'), nullable=False)
    location = db.relationship("LocationModel")
    tags = db.relationship("TagModel",secondary=tag_association_table)


class LocationModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "location"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    province = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    urbanisation = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)


class TagModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)


#SERIALISER CLASSES
class EventSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = EventModel
        load_instance = True
        include_fk = False

    location = fields.Nested('LocationSchema', many=False)
    id = auto_field(load_only=False)
    
class LocationSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = LocationModel
        load_instance = True
        include_fk = False

    id = auto_field(load_only=True)

class TagSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = TagModel
        load_instance = True
        include_fk = False

    id = auto_field(load_only=True)


#LOADER
class Events(Resource):
    def get(self):
        schema = EventSchema()
        result = db.session.query(EventModel).all()
        return schema.dump(result, many=True), 200
        

api.add_resource(Events, '/events') # Route_1
#api.add_resource(Entries, '/events/event_id/entries>') # Route_2


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(port='5002')
```

The application runs, however tags are not returned at all. the JSON output is completely missing the tags array. Any ideas?

### Attempt 2:

I've also attempted structuring my classes as [suggested here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_orm_many_to_many_relationships.htm). This also runs but doesn't provide the tag list. In this case, instead of a joining table we have a joining model as below:

```
class EventsTagsLink(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'events_tags'

   event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('events.id'), primary_key = True)
   tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('tags.id'), primary_key = True)
```

And each of the Events and Tags models have a relationship defined as previously

```
class EventModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "events"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    summary = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    scheduled = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    favourite = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    count_audio = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    count_video = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    count_articles = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'), nullable=False)
    location = db.relationship("LocationModel")
    tags = db.relationship("TagModel",secondary='events_tags')  


class TagModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    events = db.relationship("EventModel",secondary='events_tags')
```

Comment: I know this is not directly answering you question, but did you perhaps take a look at sqlacodegen? https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/ I used this for a data conversion and used the code it generated off the schema. If you have some many to many relationships see how it deals with it perhaps?

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a go

Comment: BTW: That was an SQL based as the name implies -vs JSON db.. But if you have something like the northwind or one of the Oracle sample databases lying around you can see how it would be modelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working by ensuring that I was following the documentation *accurately*.

I ended up exploring **Option 1** further.

#### The Association Table

My Original

```
tag_association_table = Table('events_tags', db.metadata,
    db.Column('event_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('events.id')),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id'))
)
```

The working version where `db.metadata` is removed and `primary_key=True` is added to each column defined in the association table.

```
tag_association_table = db.Table('events_tags',
    db.Column('event_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('events.id'),primary_key=True),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id'),primary_key=True)
)
```

#### The Event and Tag Models

My original

```
class EventModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "events"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    summary = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    scheduled = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    favourite = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    count_audio = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    count_video = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    count_articles = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'), nullable=False)
    location = db.relationship("LocationModel")
    tags = db.relationship("TagModel",secondary=tag_association_table)
```

The working version includes the value `backref="event"` against the variable `tags`

```
class EventModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "events"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    summary = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    scheduled = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    favourite = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    count_audio = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    count_video = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    count_articles = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'), nullable=False)
    location = db.relationship("LocationModel")
    tags = db.relationship("TagModel", secondary=tag_association_table, backref="event")
```

Similarly the Tag Model now contains the value `backref="tag"` against the variable `events`

```
class TagModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    events = db.relationship("EventModel", secondary=tag_association_table, backref="tag")
```

I genuinely don't understand why it is that the `backref` is singular rather than plural, or anything else for that matter. But, it works.